# Experiment where groups of dogs were treated differently to find difference in affection

Tags: reference-request, attitudes, attraction

I cannot remember where I read this, possibly [Eliezer Yudkowsky's HPMOR](http://hpmor.com/).  I'm looking to read the actual experiment and its results.

The experiment supposedly got 3 groups of dogs.  One they consistently treated with only love.  The second one was treated consistently negatively.  The third group was treated positively and negatively at random.

Supposedly the 3rd group showed the highest degree of affection towards their handlers.

Can anyone point me to the experiment, or any source or detailed description about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSauce mentions this experiment in ["Why Do We Kiss?" at 9m 24s in](https://youtu.be/ixQbCXLUUj8?t=564).

<sub>Topál, J., Miklósi, Á., Csányi, V., & Dóka, A. (1998). [Attachment behavior in dogs (Canis familiaris): a new application of Ainsworth's (1969) Strange Situation Test.](http://psycnet.apa.org/doi/10.1037/0735-7036.112.3.219) Journal of comparative psychology, 112(3), 219.</sub>

Comment: This is a great start of a good answer! Could you include the details Michael mentions in the video, needed to retrieve the study (researcher's name, described experiment) in the answer as well? In addition, could you introduce the reference you added, which isn't (or is it?) the study the OP is looking for?